Get Client IP address in Django from nginx proxy config
I have the following setup to run my Django server and I want to get a client IP address in Django server but it is giving me wrong IP address
Nginx proxy conf
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format custom_format '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                             '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                             '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /first_access.log custom_format;

    client_max_body_size 50M;
    server_tokens off;

    upstream backend {
        server backend:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        server_name www.$ENV-api.in $ENV-api.in;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /certs/server.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256';

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://backend;

            add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY" always;
            add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self';" always;
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
            add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer" always;
        }
    }
}

This above conf forward request to following nginx conf
vents {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    log_format custom_format '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                             '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                             '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /second_access.log custom_format;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    server {
        include  "/etc/nginx/mime.types";
        listen 8000;
        server_name django;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_real_ip;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://core_service:8001;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /static/;
        }

        location /media/ {
            alias /media/;
        }
    }
}

This 2nd ngnix forward request to django gunicon
In django I'm using following code to get IP address
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class GetClientIPMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0].strip()
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        request.client_ip = IP

All these 3 setups are enclosed in the docker container
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "./docker_config/certs:/certs"
    environment:
      TZ: Asia/Kolkata
      ENV: ${ENV}
    env_file:
      - .env

   core_service:
    container_name: core_service
    build: 
      context: ./docker_config/python_config
    working_dir: /home/python/app
    volumes:
    - "./microservices/core_service:/home/python/app"
    - "./docker_config/python_config/deploy_commands.sh:/deploy_commands.sh"
    - "./logs:/logs"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      TZ: Asia/Kolkata
    links:
      - redis
    command: 
       - /bin/bash
       - -c
       - |
        echo "Starting django server ..."
        /deploy_commands.sh

   backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: nginx:1.13-alpine
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      TZ: Asia/Kolkata
    volumes:
      - ./microservices/core_service/static:/static
      - ./microservices/core_service/media:/media
      - ./docker_config/python_config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./docker_config/certs:/certs

Now I'm calling one API in Django so in Django I'm getting diff IP rather than the client's actual IP.
